# Generate Grails style scaffolds on plain spring-boot (without Grails)

Tags: grails, spring-boot

One of the things I love about Grails is the ability to generate controllers and scaffolded views.

I've decided to build a new project without Grails, on Java using spring-boot. I was wondering if there was some sort of tool that will do the equivalent of the Grails 'generate-all' command that is something that will generate the controllers and views from my model so I can get a head start with my development.

I'd preferably want to create my views with thymeleaf, although I know that might be asking a bit much.